# mathspec error "Missing number, treated as zero" after TeX Live Update 2022-07-31

Tags: mathspec, texlive2022

After updating Tex Live infrastructure and thereafter the new package versions I get the following error message:

```
mathspec.sty:92: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.92 ...Symbol{\Alpha}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"41}
```

How to fix it? Or how to return to former TL version?

XeLaTeXmk refuses to compile. I am working on an urgent project. Quick answers are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

Here is my MWE, that causes the error.

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=A4]{scrbook}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[quiet]{mathspec}
%······························································
% Undo the wrong changes made by mathspec
% Patch by Ulrike Fischer
\makeatletter
\let\RequirePackage\original@RequirePackage
\let\usepackage\RequirePackage
\makeatother
%······························································
\begin{document}
%······························································
This is an empty document.
%······························································
\end{document}
```

The package ngerman clashes with mathspec. If you call it before (commented out in the MWE) mathspec, it causes the error. If you call it afterwards (the solution), the error disappears. As a consequence: (some) language dependent packages must be called therafter.

But how do we "normal" users know the right order of loading the packeges we want to use other than by hard experience?

Comment: it is hard to answer quickly,  or at all, if you provide no example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I get no error in texlive 2022 from `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\begin{document}
\end{document}`

Comment: My project worked fine until the update of today. I did not change anything. Just compiled after the update to see, if everything is in the right place, so to say. As I do not know which command or which call or which sequence of calls or other conflicts causes this error, it is hard for me to find the right lines of code or pacakge calls in my fairly huge project to dump into a MWE. I thought the error code gives some hint of what goes wrong. Please help me to find what you need.

Comment: the error is when mathspec is loaded. So probably you only need to show your preamble.

Comment: The error you show is while loading the package so you just need a document as in my comment with empty body. Start from your current preamble, delete every usepackage you can delete while showing the error, and post the resulting document in your question

Comment: Thanks, David. I too don't get an error with a MWE with updated TL. So this simple kind of MWE doesn't help to find the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: No. you will get the error if you do what I suggest, start from your document that makes the error, delete everything after mathspec, and as much as you can delete before mathspec. you can _always_ make a MWE

Comment: I will prepare a MWE tomorrow morning.

Comment: Don't use the ngerman package at all, it breaks lot of things (it makes " active already in the preamble and so breaks mathspec as shown in David's answer), use babel instead.

Comment: @ Ulrike Fischer: Thanks for your answer, but how can we avoid these kinds of problems. Where can we read which packages cause problems with other packages, which are obsolete …? If a package is obsolete, why is it still part of the system? It should be like it is with standards: once they started at different ends of a problem, when they overlap to much they will be merged into one document – and all effort goes into this one. A bit metaphoric: There are too many, too close tunnels through the same mountain. And we don't know which one is the best, until we are in it. Road signs would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get this error from

```
\documentclass{article}
\catcode`\"\active
\def"{\protect\relax}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

---

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.92 ...Symbol{\Alpha}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"41}
                                                  
?
```

so you have loaded some package making `"` active in the preamble.

---

In this case, it proved to be the obsolete `ngerman` package, which can be replaced by

```
\usepackage[german]{babel}
```

Comment: \usepackage{german} could do it ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer revenge for the football?

Comment: Thanks.
(1) But why did you move my MWE? It is a SOLUTION that just shows the problematic line of code as well – commented out. So this answer should be flagged as a solution, even it might be not the most elegant way.

Comment: (2a) The underlying second question is still unanswered. Why does this error occur after the recent TL update? If ngerman spoils mathspec in general, the problem must have popped up already before the update. So, either one of the two packeges have changed or something else now causes the problem.
(2b) This might be a hint to other potential problems.

Comment: @Franklin I did not move it (I do not have the power to do so) it was moved by the site moderator, but in general th MWE should be in the question.

Comment: @Franklin I moved your MWE as it looks like an edit to the question rather than an answer

Comment: @Franklin ctan has thousands of contributors, things change, I don't actually know what changed here, but as `ngerman` package has been an obsolete legacy interface since we introduced latex2e/babel 30 years ago, just not using it seems simpler than tracing why it eventually failed

Comment: @David Carlisle: I understand. But if the situation is so clear, why can I still use ngerman? Just remove it or give it a helpful error message like "Package ngerman is obsolete – call \usepackage[german]{babel} instead". Some other packages do that. For us "normal" users not »in the business« that long and not knowing all the historic tweaks it is even harder to grasp which package is preferable to other ones. We need instructions manuals to avoid those time consuming and easy to solve problems.

Comment: @Franklin I do not have copyright  to the package,  I can not change it.

Comment: @David Carlisle: Who can?

Comment: @Franklin whoever wrote it, see `texdoc ngerman`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. Just call ngerman after mathspec.

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=A4]{scrbook}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
%\usepackage{ngerman} Don't use it at this position
\usepackage[quiet]{mathspec}
\usepackage{ngerman}
%······························································
% Undo the wrong changes made by mathspec
% Patch by Ulrike Fischer
\makeatletter
\let\RequirePackage\original@RequirePackage
\let\usepackage\RequirePackage
\makeatother
%······························································
\begin{document}
%······························································
This is an empty document.
%······························································
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just for future reference if other people find this later: even if it works, this a very bad solution. As was pointed out in other comments here, `ngerman` was last updated in 1998 and should NOT be used nowadays. It was replaced by `babel` a long time ago (with the appropriate language option).

Comment: Why can I still use it? Just remove it or give an according error message like "Package ngerman is obsolete – call \usepackage[german]{babel} instead". Some other packages do that.

Comment: No idea. The CTAN repository isn't monitored by some central authority, so it's full of old packages that don't work anymore or shouldn't be used. Usually the author leaves a message in the CTAN page of their package explaining what the replacement is, but `ngerman` was just abandoned.

Comment: @Franklin removing obsolete packages is really not as easy as you indicate. They can not be altered by third parties so practically the only option is to remove.  But when should you remove? At the time almost every German language  document used it so removing it would have broken them all. Even now, 25 years later, most documents using it  work, it has just aquired an incompatibility with mathspec, so if it was removed  many documents would break, hopefully not so many new documents but archives like arxiv have millions of decades old documents that are expected to work with a current tex

Comment: A more reasonable question is how, as a new user, did you even know `ngerman` package exists? Is there a tutorial somewhere that should be brought in to this century? (This is a real question, we can get tutorials updated, especially wiki sites where we can fix the text directly)

Comment: @David Carlisle: Way back in 1995, when I started TeXing, I came across ngerman. Dont't remember how. So, the usual case is, you keep a package or a command that does your job, and pass it on to new documents. If there is no warning or crash, there is no reason to question and alter something. If packages or commands shall not be used anymore, we need hints; like KOMA script warned: »scrpage2 -- package obsolete and replaced by scrlayer-scrpage«. This is also helpful for new TeXnicians, because they naivly take some working documents and transport old code and habits into the future.

Comment: @David Carlisle: There are so many (to us normal users) meaningless warnings and numbers during compilation why not give some worthy information about what packages are obsolete, are not serviced anymore, have a successor …

Comment: @Franklin If Markus writes a new package and puts a warning in his old one, that is his choice. If someone writes ngerman, someone else writes babel and someone else writes mathspec and 30 years later most documents using all three still work but _you_ find some combination of package load orders gives an error.  Then who do you expect to change which file?

Comment: @Daid Carlisle: Those how KNOW and decide that a package is obsolete. I am not on changing files, but giving appropriate warnings. Where did you get your information from that ngerman is obsolete? ngerman's manual does not tell this.

Comment: @Franklin I am not sure what other documentation you could expect. If you looked at _any_ latex documentation or tutorial for the last 25 years it would show how to switch languages using babel and not mention ngerman package at all, so sure some people, really very very few, are still using a preamble copied from latex 2.09 and have never updated, but if those people are not looking at documentation, adding more text would not help.

Comment: Hand on heart: How often do study the manual of your washing machine?

Comment: … As a user, I am happy to have one solution that works. The first one is usually the best one, because than I can procede with my work. If (1) it works and (2) it is part of the system, than it is »official«, and (3) there is no reason to doubt. If (4) this 1st solution is bad from the view of enlighted people, than they must find a way to pass that information effectively to the users, not by accident.

Comment: … It is hard enough to grasp, how each package works. How to sytematically deal with interferences, latest updates, package successors, …?
It would be more effective to put the effort into helpful warnings for those »who joined the team« later, than arguing. If you tell me a way to systematically and effectively find the right information, I will take up that path at once. Two examples:
(1) I use circutikz. How to find if that package is reliable?
(2) What about mathspec? It is in version 0.2b (!) and has not changed since 2016. Is that a reliable package?
I am grateful for your answers.